# How can I set opacity in dropdown while selecting options?

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js, multi-select

I have a use-case where I have a small box where I am showing a dropdown. Now in this dropdown, while going through different options, a "Press enter to select" green box appears, but this hides the content behind.

How can I make it so that content behind is visible? Attaching a screenshot for reference. [image]

I have been able to find the CSS class for this which is:

```
multiselect__option multiselect__option--highlight
```

And these are it's CSS properties. Can I modify these somehow to make it transperant? I tried changing color from green to light yellow/pale but that didn't work.

```
.multiselect__option--highlight {
    background: #41b883;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Update: After following answer below, this is how it looks like,

[image]

Comment: positioning might be better that giving it opacity

Comment: have you tired setting the color with rgba? `rgba(65, 184, 132, 0.5);`
And if you're overriding the css, make sure you declare your css after or just use `!important` suffix

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 4):

You can make the background with opacity like this:

```
.multiselect__option--highlight {
    background: rgba(65, 184, 132, .3);
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

and if you want the words "Please enter to select" also with opacity you can do it like this:

```
.multiselect__option--highlight {
    background: #41b883;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: .3;
}
```

Comment: this works but as you can see in attached screenshot, it still overrides the value, albeit the color is less green. I followed the second choice of your answer. I see due to lack of space, this is happening. Is it possible I can just omit this message "Press enter to select" altogether. And whenever just hovers on any of the options, that is highlighted in green and text on top?

Comment: could you please post some minimal example for your component, no need to send all the code just the one related to the component you're working on.
or at least a link so I can check it out. Also please post a screenshot for the current state and another one for the desired result you wish to happen (do it with any pic editor)